# Prettier formatting with double quotes

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-standard

Anyone else come across Prettier formatting code with Double quotes instead of Single even though you
explicitly set it to replace with single in the preferences?
Here is a pic:
[image]

[image]

After a recent update to VSCode I started getting this issue and it is driving me crazy.
Any ideas as to how to fix this. Am I wrong that the Prettier: Single Quote in fact does not format with single quotes instead of double?
Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar question here (reversed problem, want double and get single quotes):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595498/prettier-in-vs-code-format-double-quotes-inside-double-quotes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to create file **.prettierrc** at package.json level  with property singleQuote set to true as below:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

Comment: I have this, an yet it suggests me to use "