# Prettier in VS Code - Format double quotes inside double quotes

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using the extension Prettier in VS Code. I want double quotes in the code. The "jsxSingleQuote" and "singleQuote" are set to false.

When I run format on this line of code

```
var hello = "\"hello\"";
```

Prettier formats it to:

```
var hello = '"hello"';
```

I want to keep double quotes and the line of code should not be formatted!

Here are the settings:

```
{
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
  "insertPragma": false,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "printWidth": 80,
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "requirePragma": false,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "useTabs": false,
  "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
  "filepath": "..../app.js",
  "parser": "babel"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is as intended. From https://github.com/prettier/prettier/tree/21733e441dc01f7d85b483edee92b7e7507bfd9a#quotes:

- If the number of quotes outweighs the other quote, the quote which is
  less used will be used to format the string - Example: "I'm double
  quoted" results in "I'm double quoted" and "This "example" is
  single quoted" results in 'This "example" is single quoted'.

Comment: You're technically correct but the question was "How to make it happen another way", not "Why it happens so".

Comment: I am facing the same issue @AndreyOzornin. I guess there is no way around it.

Comment: Same question - is there a way to force double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Try, creating file `.prettierrc` at root level, i.e sibling to package.json, with property `singleQuote` set to true as below:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, "working as intended", but doesn't fix your problem.

Check out this directory: `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-9.9.0\node_modules\prettier\`

Open up `index.js`, go to `function getPreferredQuote` and comment out or delete the following:

```
if (rawContent.includes(preferred.quote) || rawContent.includes(alternate.quote)) {
    const numPreferredQuotes = (rawContent.match(preferred.regex) || []).length;
    const numAlternateQuotes = (rawContent.match(alternate.regex) || []).length;
    result = numPreferredQuotes > numAlternateQuotes ? alternate : preferred;
}
```

Now your `result` will always be `preferred`.

(save + restart)